# Why do i have to chain $el

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Currently i'm digging a bit into Backbone.js and i wonder why i have to chain `$el` (after render()) while i'm creating a new instance of my `listItemView`.

```
    // autoCompleteView.js

    /**
     * Create a new instance of {listItem} and
     * append it to result list.
     *
     * @param item
     * @see listItem
     * @private
     */
    _addResultListItem: function (item) {

        this.$el.append(
            new this.listItem({
                model: item,
                parent: this
            }).render().$el
        );

    }
```

### Update:

#### Render method

```
    // autoCompleteView.js

    render: function () {

        // bind events
        this.input
            .keyup(this.keyup.bind(this))
            .keydown(this.keydown.bind(this))
            .after(this.$el);

        return this;
    }
```

#### ItemView

```
// autoCompleteItemView.js

var AutoCompleteItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "li",

    events: {
        "click": "select"
    },

    render: function () {
        this.$el.append( Mustache.to_html( Template, this.model.toJSON() ) );
        return this;
    },

    select: function () {
        this.options.parent.hide().select(this.model);
        return false;
    }

});

return AutoCompleteItemView;
```

#### console.log(new this.listItem({model: item, parent: this}).render());

[image: log output]

Comment: Chaining `$el` like this doesn't really make too much sense (it just refers to a jQuery object). What does your render function look like?

Comment: @m90 See my updated questions. Maybe it is an issue of my nested view?!

Comment: Thank you for your effort! I created a screenshot of my log window. It seems to return the model..

Comment: Ok, I get it, so what's happening is that `$el` refers to a jQuery-wrapped version of your View (returned by the call to `render()`). So in order to use `append()` you need to specify the view's `el` or `$el`.

Comment: Hrmmm, sounds obvious so far. Please add your comment as answer so i can accept it! Thank you!

Comment: To reflect your answer: I need to chain .el/.$el to make the render method return the list item itself instead of the model. Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`el` and `$el` (jQuery wrapped el) are the DOM Element that the view represents.

When you render, you insert/append your output to those elements.

The often used `view.$el.append(otherView.render().$el)` results from the convention (used in many examples) that render returns the view itself and the need that a view needs to be rendered, before it contains the desired content.

There is no need to chain this, you can also separate it into two statements `otherView.render()` and `view.$el.append(otherView.$el)`.